User data doesnt get stored to mongobd instance
im using express and mongoose to save data. here is my code
connection.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dribbble", {useNewUrlParser: true,})
  .then(() => console.log("connection start"));

userSchema.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    userName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    terms:Boolean,
    image:String,
    location:String,
})
const user = new mongoose.model("user",userSchema);
module.exports = user;

routes.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const user = require("../Models/userSchema");


//CREATE NEW USER PART 1
router.post("/create-user",(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const body = req.body;
    const newUser = user(body);
    newUser.save().then(newUser => {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.status(200).send(newUser);
        res.body;
    }, err => {
        res.status(400).send("Something went wrong");
    })
});

router.get("/",(req,res) => {
    user.find({}).then(function (users) {
        res.send(users);
        });
})

module.exports = router;

and index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('./DB/connection');
const router = require('./Routes/routes');
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

const PORT = 5000;

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(router);


app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`running on ${PORT}`)
})

in create-user api in route.js, i can see the first console.log but no the second one. there are no errors but still i have nothing in mongoDB Compass
i have already tried looking for problems in the schema and model but i think it looks good

What will be the value of newUser? Is it in-accordance with the userSchema. Try to console.log the value before save it to the DB.

Maybe print the real err messages instead of static string "Something went wrong" which does not provide any useful information.

This is because you're not using the new Keyword.
According to mongoose docs if you're not creating a document via modelName.create=User.create(body) then you've to first create an instance of that and then save.
There are two ways to create a document!
1:One is using the new keyword!
const newUser=new User(data) 
newUser.save().then(your logic)

2:Using create method I've mostly use the create which returns the promise.
see this examples
const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
await small.save();


